# replace part of string of multiplle element with class with JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning JS, but still have some troubles. I managed to edit a WYSIWYG editor to allow users to click a button "footnote" that inserts the following HTML:

```
<span class="footnote" data-toggle="tooltip" title="footnote">[FN]</span>
```

With some CSS I can place a number inside the element which counts upwards:

```
body {
    counter-reset: footnotecounter;
}
span.footnote:before {
    counter-increment: footnotecounter;
    content: counter(footnotecounter);
    position: relative;
    top: -0.4em;
    visibility: visible;
}

span.footnote {
    color: #0389b9;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
}
```

And example of some HTML:

```
Here is a text with a note.<span class="footnote" data-toggle="tooltip" title="footnote">[FN]</span> And there will be a second one too!<span class="footnote" data-toggle="tooltip" title="footnote">[FN]</span>
```

I actually use Popper and Twitter Bootstrap to show the content of the 'footnote' in a tooltip.

Now what I try to do, is to remove `[FN]` from all the `span` elements that have the class `footnote` with the following javascript:

```
footnotes = document.getElementsByClassName('footnote');
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++){
  footnotes[i].replace("[FN]", " ");
}
```

This does not seem to work, but I don't know where my mistake is. Also, I guess, that since I am going to use JS to alter the footnotes, I might as well leave the CSS out of it altogether and use JS to create an increasing number in all elements, right?

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dirkjf/khsg72qe/10/) to show a live example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check the *length* property of *footnotes* node list. You are trying to replace the element itself not the text inside of it. You have to replace the *textContent* or *innerText* property of the element.

Try the following way:

```js
var footnotes = document.getElementsByClassName('footnote');
for (var i = 0; i < footnotes.length; i++){
  footnotes[i].textContent = footnotes[i].textContent.replace("[FN]", " ");
}
```

```css
body {
    counter-reset: footnotecounter;
}
span.footnote:before {
    counter-increment: footnotecounter;
    content: counter(footnotecounter);
    position: relative;
    top: -0.4em;
    visibility: visible;
}

span.footnote {
    color: #0389b9;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
Here is a text with a note.<span class="footnote" data-toggle="tooltip" title="footnote">[FN]</span> And there will be a second one too!<span class="footnote" data-toggle="tooltip" title="footnote">[FN]</span>
</p>
```

**Update: As per the discussion in the comments**

```js
var footnotes = document.getElementsByClassName('footnote');
for (var i = 0; i < footnotes.length; i++){
  footnotes[i].innerHTML = footnotes[i].textContent.replace("[FN]", "<span class='new'>"+ (i+1) +"</span> ");
}
```

```css
body {
  counter-reset: footnotecounter;
}

span.new{
  position: relative;
  top: -0.4em;
  visibility: visible;
}

span.footnote {
  color: #0389b9;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
Here is a text with a note.<span class="footnote" data-toggle="tooltip" title="footnote">[FN]</span> And there will be a second one too!<span class="footnote" data-toggle="tooltip" title="footnote">[FN]</span>
Here's the number 3 thanks to CSS: <span class="footnote" data-toggle="tooltip" title="footnote">[FN]</span> and number 4 <span class="footnote" data-toggle="tooltip" title="footnote">[FN]</span>. All of this thanks to the CSS counter
</p>
```

Comment: In order to get rid of the CSS counter I changed it to `textContent.replace("[FN]", i+1)`. This seems to work, but my IDE (PHPStorm) tells me "argument types do not match paramenters". Would you say this is the correct way of doing it?

Comment: @DirkJ.Faber, what do you mean by *CSS counter*? Do you mean the for loop counter? I believe without some kind iteration you can not do that as the text you want to replace are in separate elements:)

Comment: I used to set a number within the element with `span.footnote:before` and `counter-reset: footnotecounter;` in CSS, which creates numbers 1,2,3 etc... Given that I now use JS anyways, I figured I might as well do this with `textContent.replace("[FN]", i+1)`, which works it seems... I can then remove all the CSS for creating the visible numbers. Does that make sense?

Comment: @DirkJ.Faber, as it is still not quite clear to me, could you please update the fiddle you have created so that I can see that live and suggest?

Comment: Of course, https://jsfiddle.net/dirkjf/khsg72qe/12/. All the numbering is done with CSS, not with JS. But I could also do `footnotes[i].textContent = footnotes[i].textContent.replace("[FN]", i+1);` and remove all the CSS. It's just that my IDE is giving me an error. I get the same result though.

Comment: @DirkJ.Faber, the fiddle code seems correct to me. Though I have have added another solution by replacing the text with *SPAN* element with a class and written CSS in that class. As you are having some IDE issue, you can try this:)

Comment: Cheers, that works. It does seem to be an IDE issue only, but this gets rid of the error ;)

Comment: @DirkJ.Faber, that's really grate, happy coding:)